# Programatically syncing a web project to a Linux server

Tags: shell, rsync

I have an old web project that gets rsynced to some Ubuntu box using a little script. I'm planning on using Fabric for my deployment but one thing that always bothered me - and won't be different when using Fabric - is that I never got my file access rights right.

So - I'm rsyncing all that project stuff using a different user then the one who's running the project (and of course needs at read/write access for these files) so I'm ending up with new files being created that can only be accessed by the sync-user and not by the project-user. I guess when I'm using Fabric I could "fix" the rights after syncing - so the project-user can read them - but I'm wondering if I got the problem wrong in the first place.

Maybe this isn't a problem with the scripts or the syncing but just some file access rights problem? Since I don't do Linux all day I guess that's an option. :)

I hope I could clearly state my problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I think this should be on serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Only privileged process can set owner of files it can set user id of files it creates to any other than their own.

I don't think it's reasonable to run rsync privileged from security point of view, so you have to run the synchronization as the project user.